# How to use setPromiseImplementation method from SpotifyWebAPI

Tags: javascript, promise, spotify

I want to use library `SpotifyWebApi` ([link](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/tree/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0a76bfa925d5)) with browser javascript (chrome extension).

> If you want to use a Promises/A+ library, you can set it
>
> ```
> spotifyApi.setPromiseImplementation(Q);
> ```

If I did this, raised error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Q is not defined

If like this

```
spotifyApi.setPromiseImplementation(Promise);
```

> Error handling response: TypeError: _promiseImplementation.defer is
> not a function

How to use `Promise` with this library?

Comment: Which promise library do you *want* to use? If you want to use Q.js, you'll have to load it first.

Comment: The library's custom promise implementation support seems broken: the [usage](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0/src/spotify-web-api.js#L20-L29) is different than [API compatibilty test](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0/src/spotify-web-api.js#L2065-L2080). However, the good news is that if you *don't* supply a custom promise implementation, it [falls back to the native `window.Promise`](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0/src/spotify-web-api.js#L31-L33).

Comment: @Bergi indeed, if don't call`setPromiseImplementation` and use `.then` it's works. You can write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use `Promise` with this library?

If you mean the native global `Promise`, then just do nothing - it works out of the box. You only need `setPromiseImplementation` if you want to use a custom promise library.

> How to use `setPromiseImplementation` method?

I'd argue that the functionality of that is broken. It only works with Q.js or a Q-compatible API, namely the library function that you pass would need to support both [the promise constructor pattern](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0/src/spotify-web-api.js#L2065-L2080) and [the deferred pattern](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/81f1a77461e02f2f73a284f092de0/src/spotify-web-api.js#L20-L29). If you plan to use an ES6-Promise drop-in libary and don't want to replace the native global `window.Promise`, I'd suggest to file a bug report.